# Performance issue while exporting multiple oxyplot models as png

Tags: c#, performance, oxyplot

**Summary**

When there are multiple charts that should be exported to file as PNG it introduces performance issue with memory and it blocks UI until all charts are saved.

Documentation states following:

> Warning: Calling the ExportToBitmap method often in a very short
>   period may result in high memory usage.

Problem is `ExportToFile` also calls `ExportToBitmap` and that is source of memory issue.

When trying to run this on background thread or using `Parallel.ForEach` application will crash with following message

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

**Question**

How to improve performance of `ExportToFile` when calling it multiple times from for loop?

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**

If there is `List` of `PlotModel` objects that should be exported to filesystem create `Task` for each plot model. Problem arrises with `ExportToBitmap` which requires to run on UI thread. To solve this problem create `scheduler` and start task using it.

**Example**

```
var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
foreach(var model in models) { // models is list of PlotModel objects
    var task = new Task(() => {
        var pngExporter = new PngExporter {
            Width = 1200,
            Height = 742,
            Background = OxyColors.White
        };
        pngExporter.ExportToFile(model, path); // define your own path
    });
    task.Start(scheduler);
}
```

Comment: You are running a bunch of tasks on the same thread you started with (the UI thread) due to `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`.  This is roughly equal to calling `Control.BeginInvoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.  So your solution is to continue blocking the UI thread, but pump some messages in between?

Comment: @Zer0 indeed UI thread is blocked, but at least memory usage is not increased to 2GB like it was before, it's at 100 MB instead. It solves performance issue regarding memory usage, as stated in question. Thank you for pointing out that UI thread is still blocked. What would be better solution?

Comment: Can you clarify why this reduces memory usage?  (1) Doing the exports one after another on the UI thread and (2) Doing the exports individually while pumping the message loop in between them.  I understand #2 will make the UI more responsive, but the same work is still being done on the same thread.

Comment: @Zer0 not really sure why it reduces memory usage. It's known issue in oxyplot library. My guess that it waits for `Task` to finish and then creates another one releasing memory from previous one, while without `Task` it holds memory for each object until loop finishes.